# TOPN() does not seem to do what the documentation says

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I discovered that when I have a column with 20 values of which 10 positive and 10 negative and I write a measure asking for the TOPN(15, DESC), I only get the 10 positive values.
Similarly, TOPN(15, ASC) only give the 10 negative values while it should also give the 5 smallest positive values for the function to make sense.

Am I alone in struggling with this? Is it a bug and what is a possible workaround.

Thanks in advance

Tried: TOPN(15, DESC)
Expected: 15 entries instead of the 10 I got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RANKX as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice and tried to make a separate table using RANKX() like this

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL(Table1), Table1[Column])
```

It ranks all items in Table1 based on the aforementioned column. The ALL(Table1) function removes any filters from the Table1 table, so that the ranking is based on the entire table.

Next, I used (in the table I was creating)

```
Value = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Values]], FILTER(ALL(Table1), [Rank] <= 15))
```

which, given an external filter context, will return the appropriate value of nothing in case not within the TOP 15.

Although it works, it still seems a cumbersome way to do this and I still don't understand why TOPN() cannot work with crossing the 0 value.

Thanks for your suggestion Morph